# How to show date in php. using getFormatDateTime and strtotime

Tags: php, wordpress, date, strtotime

Before I start I should mention that I have no knowledge about coding, so please bear with me if my question doesn't make sense.
I bought a plugin for taxi reservation for wordpress. Everything works fine except that when the user picks the date after checking out in woocommerce the reservation date and time is changed to: `01-01-1970 12:00 AM` and therefore all dates are wrong in emailed receipts as well as the woocommerce orders section.

Since the author is not providing any support on this, I had to dig into it myself and I noticed it's using the following to show the date after checkout:

`$dateTimePickUp = date(getFormatDateTime("php"),strtotime(WC()->session->get_post_meta( $order_id , 'dateTimePickUp', true )));`

Since this was not working I used the code the was used before checkout:

`$dateTimePickUp = date(getFormatDateTime("php"),strtotime(WC()->session->get( 'dateTimePickUp' )));`

Now everything is fine except that in the woocommerce orders section I'm getting a Fatal error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in
>   /data/49/4/64/130/4716619/user/5589202/htdocs/OCRides/wp-con‌​tent/plugins/stern_t‌​axi_fare/templates/c‌​heckout/checkoutAfte‌​r.php
>   on line 21

Now my questions are:

1. What's the difference between the above codes?
2. How can I make the first code work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use date to format the timestamp

Comment: what is the fatal error? can post the error message in the description.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in /data/49/4/64/130/4716619/user/5589202/htdocs/OCRides/wp-content/plugins/stern_taxi_fare/templates/checkout/checkoutAfter.php on line 21

Comment: It seems we will need to know what `WC()->session->get_post_meta( $order_id , 'dateTimePickUp', true )` is doing.  Please update your question with (minimal) relevant code from it.

Answer (score 0):

After comparing some of the other calls with `get_post_meta()`, it seems to me that this may be a simple typo where an underscore (`_`) is missing.

Change:

```
$dateTimePickUp=date(getFormatDateTime("php"),strtotime(WC()->session->get_post_meta($order_id,'dateTimePickUp',true)));
```

To:

```
$dateTimePickUp=date(getFormatDateTime("php"),strtotime(WC()->session->get_post_meta($order_id,'_dateTimePickUp',true)));
```